# Adding MySql to playframework 2.2.1

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to connect to a mysql database using the play framework. From my own searching, I know I need to add this line somewhere:

`"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"`

However, in every documentation/similar question it says that this line either goes into the `Build.scala` file or the `build.sbt` file and I have **neither** of those files. When I created my application (as a java app) it only gave me a `build.properties` and `plugins.sbt` which are inside the project folder.

Does anyone know how where to add this line? Do I need to create one of those files?

My `build.properties` file:

```
 sbt.version=0.13.0
```

And

`plugins.sbt`

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

UPDATE: After adding

`addSbtPlugin("mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18")` to my plugins file:

[image]

Comment: That's odd. `build.sbt` should be in the root directory, that is, if your app is called MyPlay2App, the path to it should be MyPlay2App/build.sbt I just tried this out on a mac using the command line tool. You can also try to add `build.sbt` at the root level. My default `build.sbt` contains the following: 

`version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"`

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are required to add lines in your sbt file.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 jdbc,
 anorm,
 cache,
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)
```

And after that change into your `application.config` by uncommenting

```
#
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
db.default.user="root"
db.default.password=""
```

Comment: Which sbt file? I tried adding them to the `plugins.sbt` and that did not work.

Comment: this one is build.sbt

Comment: I don't have a `build.sbt` file, as I said in the question.

Comment: have you eclipsify your project ? because it presents in java project too.

Comment: It is an intellij project

Comment: Adding it to the `build.sbt` file is correct, and somehow my project just didn't have that file. Maybe I accidentally deleted it...who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18")
```

Comment: This seesm to be on the right track. I am getting an unresolved dependency error though. Ill update my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the build file here `$YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\project\Build.scala` ?

plugins.sbt should contain this:

```
// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

and in Build.scala you should have this:

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
  )
```

To be honest with you it would be best for you to run the play executable and create the project and not from IDEA.

The cmd is:
`$ play new myAppName`

then use the sbt plugin for IDEA or if you have IDEA 13 you could import the project using the SBT.

`https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea`